# How to change font size with longtable environment while endfloat?

Tags: tables, fonts, longtable, endfloat

The following code only changes the font of placeholder rather than my texts in the table. Any method to fix that? thanks for the help!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[nolists,noheads]{endfloat}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{longtable}{table}


\begin{document}

{
\tiny 
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{table:label}  \\ 
    \hline
    1&2&3 \\
    asdf&sadf&adsf\\
    cxvb&xvcb&xvcb\\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
 }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[nolists,noheads]{endfloat}
\newenvironment{tinylongtable}{\tiny}{}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor{tinylongtable}{table}


\begin{document}


\begin{tinylongtable}
\begin{longtable}{ccc}
    \caption{caption}
    \label{table:label}  \\
    \hline
    1&2&3 \\
    asdf&sadf&adsf\\
    cxvb&xvcb&xvcb\\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{tinylongtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! It works!